# deb file not found after install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, filesystem

I installed nmon on Ubuntu 16.04 as below.

At the time of installation, I can see the file `nmon_14g+debian-1build1_amd64.deb` downloading, unpacking and installing. After the installation nmon is working fine.

But when I tried to see the downloaded file at the location  `/var/cache/apt/archives/` it is not there. I tried to search on the entire system with root id, but I am not able see the file `nmon_14g+debian-1build1_amd64.deb`.

I tried `updatedb` and `locate *.deb` as root but I can't find it!

Can anyone help me figure out where this file has actually gone?

```
$ nmon
The program 'nmon' is currently not installed. 
You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install nmon


$ sudo apt install nmon
[sudo] password for thom: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nmon
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 333 not upgraded.
Need to get 45.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 173 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 nmon amd64 14g+debian-1build1 [45.9 kB]
Fetched 45.9 kB in 6s (6,897 B/s)                                              
Selecting previously unselected package nmon.
(Reading database ... 180965 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nmon_14g+debian-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nmon (14g+debian-1build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up nmon (14g+debian-1build1) ...
```

Comment: Apt deletes package files once they're downloaded. Is there any reason you want it to be there?

Comment: @Thomas Can you **[edit]** your question with the output of `ls -al /var/cache/apt/archives`, as well as `locate -r '\.deb$'` (which is the `locate` command I think you want)? After pasting text from the terminal into your question, you can select it and press Ctrl+K or click **{}** to format it as code so it is readable. I don't expect `locate *.deb` to work, manly since `*` expands to the list of the files in the current directory, so that command just shows files whose names contain the full name of some file in the current directory with `.deb` appended, which surely isn't what you want.

Comment: @EliahKagan see linked post^

Comment: @muru Thanks. I'm don't know why `.deb`s I've installed or upgraded with `apt` sometimes to remain in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, as I don't seem have custom configuration to prevent their removal. But I noticed if I download a `.deb` (`sudo apt install --download-only <package>`) then install it (`sudo apt install <package>`), the file remains, so maybe the files left over are package upgrades that were automatically downloaded (which I have configured to occur) and manually upgraded. *Thomas:* I've added my duplicate vote but still think it could be useful if you added the above information.